# How to assign opening hours of 24/7 in Google Places?

Tags: google-my-business

I'm creating a CSV for import in Google Places. Some of my rows have limited opening hours, whereas others are open 24/7, thus I need to include the hours column.

Do I have to include the opening hours for the 24/7 items like this:

```
1:00:00:23:59:2:00:00:23:59:3:00:00:23:59:4:00:00:23:59:5:00:00:23:59:6:00:00:23:59:7:00:00:23:59
```

...or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Doing a bit of searching I ran into this blog comment that had some text from a [Google Support Email reply](http://blumenthals.com/blog/2011/12/21/the-untold-story-of-2011-googles-significant-investments-in-google-places-support-structure/#comment-565603)

> “The underlying issue is that the system is not taking 12am-12am as valid operating hours” and “After speaking with our technical team members, your hours may or may not be listed as 12am to 12am after the next index push. There is the option not to display hours, which may be better suited for a 24 hours business, such as yourself.”

The blog comment was made on 1/6/2012 so this is a timely answer (hopefully they fix it).

**A Possible Solution** is to add to the `Additional Details` section with `Open 24 Hours`:`Yes`

Just for kicks I'll throw in the [link](http://blumenthals.com/blog/2012/01/24/catalog-of-current-bugs-in-google-places-and-the-google-places-dashboard/) I found that through since it lists bugs known in the Places and Places Dashboard.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For now, I leave out the opening hours to imply 24/7 as suggested in the comment.